# SKAdNetwork using Firebase SDK and Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, skadnetwork

I am looking to integrate Firebase Analytics SDK into my apps, to be able to link with Google Ads so we can track ad campaign and attribution. Since our apps target kids space, we are not allowed to use any IDFA capabilities by Apple, so using anything like AdSupport.framework or ATT (App Tracking Transparency) it will risk app rejection. So, that leaves SKAdNework. According to Firebase Notes (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6290_-_july_28_2020), SKAdNetwork will register for AdNetwork attribution automatically called on first open by default, and by setting the following key `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_REGISTRATION_WITH_AD_NETWORK_ENABLED YES` in our `Info.plist` file, should opt in to this default behaviour. However, I have no way to verify this on device (i.e. I see no console message on the device, nor can't find this call in the code `[SKAdNetwork registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution]`)

Is there anything else I am missing? Do I need to add SKAdNetwork Identifiers to my plist file, like this (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14#skadnetwork)?

Bellow is a sample copy of my pod file:

```
target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport', '8.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '8.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '8.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '8.6.0'
end
```